# Google not displaying meta description

Tags: html, css, meta

I've recently hosted my website nepalride.com. I have included meta description in all pages but google is not not showing them. You can see here:
https://www.google.com.np/?gws_rd=cr&ei=U-zcWIKnHIKYvQSChZCwCw#q=nepalride.com&*

I've used my meta description like:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Nepal Ride|Tested and Reconditioned Bikes and Cars near you</title>
<meta name="description" content="Browse from over 1000+ genuine and tested Second hand Bikes and Cars from over 100+ recondition houses in Nepal."/>
<meta name="keyword" content="used bikes,used cars,used bike,used cars,second hand bike,second hand bikes,second car,second hand cars,second hand scooter,second hand scooters,used scooters,2nd hand bikes,second hand online,second hand bikes for sale,second hand shop,nepalride"/>        
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">.
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ***"I've recently hosted my website"***  google crawler takes time to show meta description or page content or to index your website, crawl pattern could be slow, sometimes more than a month. So have patience.

Comment: google crawl take times to crawl your website details and refresh your search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google to show what's in your meta description, it needs to appear in the page also. Here is a link to a similiar question i once ask:[How to add description to SERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698495/how-to-add-description-to-serp)

Comment: @OP, did you try using **info:nepalride.com** as the search query? I did and saw some description-like stuffs.

Comment: So should i do nothing?

Comment: @Anon, just make sure what's in your meta tag is also found somewhere on your page.